# using dict to connect items

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, count

I have taken data from a text file, and currently have a list that contains numerous urls, some of which repeat, and unix timestamps (tab delimited). I want to create an output that has each unique url, the number of times the url occurs, and the time of the earliest occurrence. This is what the data look like:

```
url1     1441076681663   
url2     1441076234873   
url2     1441123894050   
url2     1441432348975   
url3     1441659082347   
url1     1441450392840
```

I would like this to be my output, in a csv file:

```
url    count    time
url1    2       1441076681663
url2    3       1441076234873
url3    1       1441659082347
```

I was thinking of using a dictionary, but I am not sure how you would replace the time with the earliest occurrence. maybe some sort of for/if loop?

Comment: Yes. A dictionary would work. With some sort of `for` loop with `if` statements. Why not try that out and ask specific questions when you get stuck with that?

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using only Python standard libraries.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        url, timestamp = line.split()
        d[url].append(int(timestamp))

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['url', 'count', 'time'])
    for url, timestamps in d.items():
        writer.writerow([url, len(timestamps), min(timestamps)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your url as a key to dictionary as it will always be unique and you can maintain dictionary something like

```
Dict = {url1 : [mintime, count]} #to track minimum and count
```

or

```
Dict = {url1 : [time1, time2, time3]} #to track all timestamps, 
# I would prefer this one if you don't space constraint as you would get more info
```

Code for second data structure

```
Dict = {} #empty dictionary

with open("file.txt", "r") as file: #reading file
    for line in file.readlines():
        if len(line) > 0:
               mylist = line.split() #spliting with tab
               key = mylist[0]
               value = mylist[1]
               if key in Dict:
                   Dict[key].append(value) #if url already exists as key
               else:
                    Dict[key] = [value]
        else:
            print "No more lines to render"

    print Dict
```

Comment: This does not work at all: `for lines in file.readlines()` already iterates over lines, so `for line in lines` breaks each line into characters.

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso, thank you so much for letting me know. I have updated the code, it was probably because of the rush. I would kindly request you to remove negative vote if you did it.

Answer (score -1):

This is an instance where a Counter object might also be useful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Here's an implementation:

```
from collections import Counter

# Get list of data
my_list = []
my_list.append(('url1', 1441076681663))
my_list.append(('url2', 1441076234873))
my_list.append(('url2', 1441123894050))
my_list.append(('url2', 1441432348975))
my_list.append(('url3', 1441659082347))
my_list.append(('url1', 1441450392840))

# First get the count
my_counter = Counter([pair[0] for pair in my_list])

# Then find the first instance
my_dict = {}

for pair in my_list:

    key = pair[0]
    val = pair[1]
    if (key not in my_dict) or (my_dict[key] > val):
        my_dict[key] = val

print "URL\tCount\tFirst Instance"
for key in my_dict:
    print key, my_counter[key], my_dict[key]
```

Comment: Caveat emptor: this presupposes that timestamps are sorted, either globally or by url.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', names=['url', 'timestamp'],
                 header=None, delim_whitespace=True)

output = df.groupby('url')['timestamp'].agg({'count': 'size', 'time': 'min'})
output.to_csv('output.csv')
```